# jquery autocomplete not sure how to load the C# handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got a simple textbox on my asp.net page wrapped around an updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipToName" runat="server" 
                                            ToolTip="Enter a name such as a company name or contact name." 
                                            MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Trying to implement autocomplete...so I created an .ashx file (an IHttpHandler) like so:

```
 public class LoadAddress : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            DataSet ds;
            Dictionary<long, string> lstAddresses = new Dictionary<long, string>();

            ds = BL.GetAddresses(string.Empty, "both", 0, 100); //just snatching some data...

            foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                lstAddresses.Add(Convert.ToInt64(dr["AddressID"].ToString()), dr["Name"].ToString());
            }

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<long, string> item in lstAddresses)
            {
                builder.Append(string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}",
                      item.Value,
                      item.Key,
                      Environment.NewLine));
            }

            context.Response.Write(builder.ToString());
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to call it in jquery, I tried:

```
 $("#<%= txtShipToName.ClientID %>").autocomplete('LoadAddress.ashx').
        result(function (event, data, formatted) { // data[0] : Address, data[1] : Address ID
        });
```

But result is undefined, notice this method doesnt even exist...how can I call LoadAddress.ashx?

## Edit

I added into the web config file:

```
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="LoadAddress.ashx" type="MyShipper.LoadAddress"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

But the autocomplete doesnt seem to work...in the jquery I changed it to simply:

`$("#<%= txtShipToName.ClientID %>").autocomplete('LoadAddress.ashx');`

But like I said no autocomplete is coming up.  No errors in the developers tools in chrome.
What could I be missing?

Comment: Please can anyone help me with this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered your `LoadAddress` handler in the web.config?

(iis 6):

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="LoadAddress.ashx" type="NameOfClass, NameOfAssembly"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

(and for iis 7+):

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
      <add name="LoadAddress" verb="*" path="LoadAddress.ashx" type="NameOfClass, NameOfAssembly"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi @TimDog, what would I enter for nameofclass and nameofassembly?  For nameofclass do I give it the class name of the ASHX file?  For instance in my above example LoadAddress?

Comment: @oJM86o - for NameOfClass you give it the full path (including namespaces) to your class. So MyNamespace.LoadAddress would be the first param; the second is the actual name of the compiled DLL (minus the .dll extension). So if you compiled into MyLibrary.dll, you'd put type="MyNamespace.LoadAddress, MyLibrary"